Как в oxyplot задать цвет неактивного элемента легенды?
Пытаюсь задать цвет неактивного элемента в легенде в oxyplot

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Чтобы задать цвет неактивного элемента легенды в oxyplot, можно использовать следующее свойство:
plotModel.Legends.Add(new Legend() {
  SeriesInvisibleTextColor = OxyColor.FromArgb(255, 113, 113, 113)});

